# Vue app cannot connect to socket server hosted on nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to connect to node js server hosted on same server as the web application, but it returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` errors.

And node server is running on background using `PM2` and the process is running without any issue.

In web application i have tried using both IP address of the server and localhost, whenever localhost is used it returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `TIMED_OUT` for if IP address is given.

this is the nginx config for node server,

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name server_ip;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    }
```

i'm not sure what went wrong here. Pleases help me out. Thanks in advance.